# Error Connection Null

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, jtds

I am trying to execute the following code, which connects my android application to mysql server through JDBC:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.*;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(this, "SqlConnection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://HOSTNAME/DATABASE_NAME;user=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from  Tablename;");

            if(reset.next() == true){
                //Log.w("Data", reset.getString(1));
                Toast.makeText(this, reset.getString(1) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //Log.w("Error Connection", ""+e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Connection" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I've added the jtds 1.2.7 in my project, and added the internet permission, The result is Connection ConnectionNull

Comment: *Where* does the error occur?

Comment: I think the url is wrong

Comment: @rocking what's the right format for it ?, does it depend on the host am connecting to ? or it's the same format for all!?

Comment: @JonSkeet, the error occur when i run the application !

Comment: You should be logging the exception, and then the exception will contain the line number in the stack trace...

Comment: @Izzo32 I dont think there is a jtds driver for mysql.I know there are jtdc driver for ms sql server but have not heard if it is also present for mysql also

Comment: i've tried it with ms sql too but it's the same error @rocking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe jTDS is used to work with MS SQL server and not mysql. 
For connecting to mysql, you would use something like this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection`enter code here`("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password")
```

For connecting to MS SQL server using jTDS, you would do something like this, with a port number and instance name :

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:<instance_port>/Payroll
```

Comment: That's right, i did this but now i guess i am having a problem with the URL, it's giving me the following error:

Comment: That's right, i did this but now i guess i am having a problem with the URL, it's giving me the following error:

Error connection Communications link failure.

I am using phpmyadmin, and i can't find the connection string for it :/